# Initialization process of WebApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am learning spring MVC, Can someone tell me when WebApplicationCotext gets initialized? and who is responsible to initialize WebApplicationContext?

Comment: Is it a Spring Boot application?

Comment: No, Its Spring MVC.

Comment: Please try googling something first otherwise it shows lack of effort 

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/web.html#spring-web

Answer (score 0):

i think it is initialized in the first time when the app runs, here is my log when spring webapp starts, the server container is reponsible to it?

[image: spring atartup log]